# Indy10 TCP; client for Android and server for win32

Tags: android, delphi, tcp, indy

I'm new in INDY library, so I use delphi XE8 and indy for TCP client/serverconnection; I built server application for Windows and client for Android, when client application send message"text" to server application it work but the client app don't receive anything:

```
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('OK'+edit2.Text+inttostr(incr), IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault());

LLine := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn();
```

LLine variable is empty and the client don't receive anything from the server app.

I repeat that the client app is created for Android and the server for WIN32 when I tested the client/sever app for WIN32 it work fine but when I test client app for Android, the client app is connected and the server app receive the data but client app don't receive anything.

The Server side code is :

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
LLine: String;
begin
TIdNotify.NotifyMethod( ShowStartServerdMessage );
LLine := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
if ((char(LLine[1])='O') and (char(LLine[2])='K'))  then
  begin
  tg.text:=sg.text;ta.text:=sa.text;
  sg.text:=fg.text;sa.text:=fa.text;
  fg.text:=(char(LLine[3]));fa.text:=(char(LLine[4]))+(char(LLine[5]))+(char(LLine[6]));
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('OK'+fa.text);
  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(StopStartServerdMessage);
 sndPlaySound('C:\defi', SND_NODEFAULT Or SND_ASYNC );
  end
else
  if (char(LLine[1])='C') then
  begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('OK'+fa.text);
  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod(StopStartServerdMessage);
  end;
end;
```

And the Client side :

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
LLine2: String;
begin
if timer1.Enabled=false then
begin timer1.Enabled:=true;label4.text:=edit3.Text; end;
incr:=strtoint(label4.text);
incr:=incr+1;
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('OK'+edit2.Text+inttostr(incr), IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
LLine2 := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn();
if ((char(LLine2[1])='O') and (char(LLine2[2])='K')) then
begin
Memo1.Lines.Add('La commande est reçu par le serveur');
end;
end;
```

And in client side i have a timer on event of timer i have this code :

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
s:string;
begin
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('C', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
s := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn();
if ((char(s[1])='O') and (char(s[2])='K'))  then
begin
label4.text:=char(s[3])+char(s[4])+char(s[5]);
end;
end;
```

Comment: Using `IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault` as encoding is dangerous, because the server does not know which OS the client uses. Maybe this is the reason why it works when both client and server are on the same box. So it could help to include the server side code too in your question.

Comment: ok, in server side , and in execute event of idtcpserver i put :

  TIdNotify.NotifyMethod( ShowStartServerdMessage );
  LLine := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault);
  For i:= 1 to (LLine.Length)Do
   Begin
      Mot[i]:=char(LLine[i]); 
   End;
      @mjn

Comment: @MedBen: The client is trying to read a line from the server. Where is the server code that actually sends that line to the client? Please don't put code in comments, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34796153/edit) and put your code there instead. And yes, please don't use `OSDefault` across machines. Use a standardized encoding instead, like `UTF8`. Character data conversion errors tend to cause loss of data.  Neither Indy or Embarcadero raise errors on byte->char conversion errors at runtime, it is possible for no chars (empty strings) to be returned instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i have changed my code , i use UTF8 and the code still don't work

Comment: In your server code what are `tg`, `sg`, `ta`, etc? Since you are accessing their `text` members, are they UI controls? If so, you CANNOT safely access them directly. The `TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` event runs in a worker thread. You must synchronize with the main UI thread to access UI controls safely. I presume you already know that, given your use of `TIdNotify`. BTW, why are you doing single character comparisons instead of substring comparisons? Indy even has functions for that, such as: `if TextStartsWith(LLine, 'OK') then`. And your timer code is still using `OSDefault`

Comment: And things like `(char(LLine[4]))+(char(LLine[5]))+(char(LLine[6]))` can be simplified to `Copy(LLine, 4, 3)` instead.

Comment: tg, sg ,ta are just labels, i have changed in timer code indyTextEncoding_UTF8, and the code still don't work, yes i know that  onexecute event runs worker thread, i use single chracter because i will use this program for electronics board i will send characters to microcontrollers, between two Windows apps it's work fine but if i use Android app, it send a data but it can't receive.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau it work very well, thank you the problem was a indyTextEncoding_UTF8 and single character comparison the Copy(LLine,4,3) it's work better then char(s[4])+..., i will test the Windows app with microcontrollers, the communication between microcontrollers and Win app will be through USB i'll send single character as command to electronic board, Thank you

Comment: @MedBen: You still can't directly access UI controls safely in a worker thread. Your updates to the `Text` properties **MUST** be synchronized properly, otherwise you risk crashing your code, causing deadlocks, even killing the UI so it can't receive messages anymore (let alone process them). UI components **are not thread safe**.

Comment: i've changed my code,i've synchronized the TIdTCPServer.OnExecute event with the main UI thread to access UI controls safely,the updates of the Text properties are in main UI, thank you for that @Remy Lebeau